# How to add create and edit form?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I wanted to add create and edit option for following pname field . in new form i want only one field and after adding name save it and it should display in selection list i.e new nmae added?

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv

class asset_asset(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "asset.asset"
    _columns = {
        'asse_line':fields.one2many('asset.line','emp_id','Name Plate'),
    }
asset_asset()

class asset_line(osv.osv):
    _name="asset.line"
    APPOINTMENT_SELECTION=[
        ('0','Regular'),
        ('1','Aditional'),
        ('2','Deputation'),

    ]
    _columns = {
        'pname':fields.selection(APPOINTMENT_SELECTION,'Parameter Type'),
        'vsurname':fields.char('Value'),

        'emp_id': fields.many2one('asset.asset', 'vendor_id'),
    }

asset_line()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Better Way is that you should create a new object for **pname field** as **many2one field**

some think like this

```
class pname_line(osv.osv):
    _name='pname.line'
    _columns = {
        'code':fields.char('Code'),
        'name':fields.char('Name'),
    }
```

And use that object in **asset.line**  as **many2one**

```
class asset_line(osv.osv):
    _columns = {
        'pname_id':fields.many2one('pname.line','Pname'),
        'vsurname':fields.char('Value'),
        'emp_id': fields.many2one('asset.asset', 'vendor_id'),
    }
```

I hope this should helpful for you .. :)